# Remove add printer permissions

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, printing

I want to remove the permission to add/remove printers on the computers of my domain to all users (except admins). Can I do this via the domain policy?

Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking if you can prevent users from installing local printers.  Or are you asking if you can prevent them from connecting to network printers?  Are your users administrators on their local machine?

Comment: They are not admins. I want to prevent them from installing local printers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default if a user is not a member of the local administrator or power users group they cannot add printers.

Comment: Are you sure. I have a computer with a localy connected printer and every once in a while I find this printer duplicated and the original printer disconnected (grayed out in the Printers "folder")... Any other possible cause?